# Ignore subpackage using Flutter pub?

Tags: flutter, package, dependencies

We're only supporting Android and iOS, but we're getting a version conflict with a web subpackage (maplibre_gl_web) of a package (flutter-maplibre-gl) we're using, namely:

> Because every version of maplibre_gl_web from git depends on image ^3.0.2 and flutter_launcher_icons >=0.12.0 depends on image ^4.0.15, maplibre_gl_web from git is incompatible with flutter_launcher_icons >=0.12.0.

Is there a way to resolve this by excluding the unused subpackage?

Comment: I don't think you can exclude a dependent package, but have you tried using [`dependency_overrides`](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides) to force using a specific version of `image`?

Comment: @jamesdlin Could you elaborate? I'd think both packages would see the images version in dependencies, so version resolution would still fail.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Adding `image: ^4.0.15` to `dependency_overrides` should force the use of `image: ^4.0.15` in your entire dependency graph.  I'm hoping that since you don't actually use `maplibre_gl_web` that any incompatibilities it has with `image: ^4.0.15` won't break your build.

Comment: @jamesdlin I didn't try it; the dependencies are used for dependency resolution, not the dependency_overrides, and that resolution is what's failing.

Comment: Huh?  The whole point of using `dependency_overrides` is to force dependency resolution to work.  I don't understand why you won't try it since adding the `dependency_overrides` line I suggested would take less than a minute to try.  Just now I created a Flutter project myself, added dependencies on `maplibre_gl` and `flutter_launcher_icons`, ran `flutter pub get`, got the same error as you, added the `dependency_overrides` line, and then ran `flutter pub get` successfully. (I don't know if there will be compile-time errors later, however.)

Comment: @jamesdlin Just tried it, and it worked! I did not think that would work from the doc you linked in your comment above, but it appears that dependency_overrides aren't version-checked? Want to explain in an answer and I'll accept?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "dependency_overrides aren't version-checked".   `dependency_overrides` override all other version constraints.

Comment: By 'not version-checked', I meant the dependency is forced in spite of the specified version required; I assumed the version numbers would still need to fit into those constraints.

Comment: Ah, now I understand your misunderstanding.  You thought that it would just pin a specific version that conformed to other constraints.  But if someone wanted that, they could just use a normal `dependencies` entry (`image: 4.0.15` (no caret)) which would just add a constraint that `pub` would try to satisfy alongside the other constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to exclude a transitive dependency, but you can use [`dependency_overrides`](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides) to override version constraints for transitive dependencies.  That is, you should be able to do:

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  image: ^4.0.15
```

to force all uses of `package:image` in your dependency graph to use version 4.0.15 (or a compatible version).  That is, it would force `maplibre_gl_web` to use a `image: ^4.0.15` dependency.

Note that doing so might break the `maplibre_gl_web` package, but since you're not actually using that, that might be okay.

Alternatively, you could override the `maplibre_gl_web` dependency itself and point it to an empty package:

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  maplibre_gl_web:
    path: fake_maplibre_gl_web
```

and then create a `fake_maplibre_gl_web` subdirectory with its own `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
name: maplibre_gl_web
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.0.0
```

The empty package approach is a bit more work but would be functionally equivalent to excluding the package.  It's also probably a bit safer since it wouldn't override whatever version of the `image` package `flutter_launcher_icons` wants to use.