# For a Flutter package, is it possible to remove dependecies related to unused platforms?

Tags: flutter

I am developing an Android/IOS app. The app is definitely not intended for Windows, yet i get dependency conflicts over different versions of Win32...
Say these two packages:
package_info_plus: ^4.1.0
wakelock: ^0.6.2

This is really frustrating, is there way to use the packages for the target OSses only?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76266062/