# Flutter - How to remove unnecessary package constraint that causes version resolving issues?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, flutter-pubspec

Right now I'm trying to update my packages in my Flutter project. But I can't because there are constraints and then more constraints and then more constraints.

At the very bottom of the "issue" right now is that one package is dependended on "Web" which is not relevant to my project but I can't solve my versioning due to this.

So, this is the case:

```
video_player_media_kit depends on wakelock_plus (fixed to ^1.1.1)
wake_lock_plus depends on package_info_plus
share_plus depends on package_info_plus
battery_plus depends on package_info_plus
device_info_plus depends on package_info_plus
```

So, fix package_info_plus right?
No, that's because device_info_plus requires 'web' >= 0.5.0 <= 0.6.0
So device_info_plus is incompatible with the downgrade.
And it's incompatible with the upgrade.

But the real question I ask is I don't use Web plugins, or run it in Web-mode at all; I even deleted the 'Web' folder (only reference to how to delete support was this that I've found) that was accidently added during the creation of the project - so how can I just skip this altogether and ignore this warning for all forseeable future?

If one plugin is dependent upon 'Web' which is very specific in this case. How and what should I to resolve my dependency issues that are mainly due to a idiotic package system? It's node modules all over again. Except, with perhaps, some better constraints.

Comment: Does [Ignore subpackage using Flutter pub?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76238222/) help?

Comment: I have used dependency_overrides once before for http package. This did not work with web set to a specific version.

Comment: And creating a dummy package doesn't work?

Comment: Can you provide the dependencies section of your pubspec.yaml?